# How to randomize a position for my input with JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a little game that is about a questions-answers game, that has 3 options and only one is the right one. So, what I'm trying to do is, every time I open the page, I randomize the correct answer, so, the player can't just memorize the positions, he will be obligate to remember the true answer. I already know how to randomize the right button, doing it with a random number and stuff like that, but, with this problem, just randomize the right button isn't what I need, cuz I have to change the position of the answer too. So, this is my code.

```js
const vintecinco = document.getElementById('312');
const vinteseis = document.getElementById('314');
const vintesete = document.getElementById('214');

vinteseis.addEventListener('click', acerto);

function acerto() {
  var msg = document.createElement('p');
  msg.textContent = 'Voce acertou!';
  msg.style.cssText = 'color: green;'
  document.body.appendChild(msg);
  var prosseguir = document.createElement('a');
  prosseguir.textContent = 'Próxima pergunta!'
  prosseguir.href = 'q3.html';
  document.body.appendChild(prosseguir);
  vintecinco.disabled = true;
  vinteseis.disabled = true;
  vintesete.disabled = true;
}

vintecinco.addEventListener('click', erro);

vintesete.addEventListener('click', erro);

function erro() {
  var msgerro = document.createElement('p');
  msgerro.textContent = "Voce errou!";
  msgerro.style.cssText = 'color: red;';
  document.body.appendChild(msgerro);
  var voltar = document.createElement('a');
  voltar.textContent = 'Recomeçar!'
  voltar.href = 'index.html';
  document.body.appendChild(voltar);
  vintecinco.disabled = true;
  vinteseis.disabled = true;
  vintesete.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Qual o número de pi?</p>
  <input type="submit" value="3,12..." id='312'>
  <input type="submit" value="2,14..." id='214'>
  <input type="submit" value="3,14..." id='314'>
</main>
```

What kind of thing I could do to get random positions without compromise my right answer?

Now I did some changes and I created a test file. I'm trying to do something like that, but now, I can't change the value of the 2 wrong answers, they're default. How could I change it?

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
console.log(i);
var button = document.getElementById('btn' + i);
if(random == i) {
        button.addEventListener('click', prize);
        button.value = '1';
}
else {
        button.addEventListener('click', closewindow);
        button.value = '2';
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an attempt to do what you're asking here. Either create the nodes or values in a random order from an Array using `yourArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]`.

Comment: Randomize the `value`s instead. You'll need to track which id has the correct answer.

Comment: I want to randomize the value with the right answer. Doing the Math.random, I don't think that I can do this. Maybe something like my new changes, but I can't change now the value of the two other wrong buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want, depending on the rest of the application, one or the other may be better for you, an example:

```js
    var input = [];

function acerto() {
  var msg = document.createElement('p');
  msg.textContent = 'Voce acertou!';
  msg.style.cssText = 'color: green;'
  document.body.appendChild(msg);
  var prosseguir = document.createElement('a');
  prosseguir.textContent = 'Próxima pergunta!'
  prosseguir.href = 'q3.html';
  document.body.appendChild(prosseguir);

  input.forEach((i)=>{
    i.disabled = true;
  });
  input = [];
}

function erro() {
  var msgerro = document.createElement('p');
  msgerro.textContent = "Voce errou!";
  msgerro.style.cssText = 'color: red;';
  document.body.appendChild(msgerro);
  var voltar = document.createElement('a');
  voltar.textContent = 'Recomeçar!'
  voltar.href = 'index.html';
  document.body.appendChild(voltar);

  input.forEach((i)=>{
    i.disabled = true;
  });
  input = [];
}

  // question, true, false, false...
  var res = ["Qual o número de pi?", "3.14", "2.14", "3.12"];
  var quest = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];

  // Create Question
  quest.innerHTML = "<p>" + res.splice(0, 1)[0] + "</p>";

  // Create Random input
  for(i in res){
    let temp = document.createElement('input');
    temp.type = "submit";
    temp.value = res[i];
    if(i == 0){
      temp.addEventListener('click', acerto);
    }else{
      temp.addEventListener('click', erro);
    }

    let rand = Math.floor((input.length+1) * Math.random());
    input.splice(rand, 0, temp);
  }

  // Show input
  input.forEach((i)=>{
    quest.appendChild(i);
  });
```

```html
<main>
</main>
```